# How to optimize work with HashMap in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

everybody.
Today I wrote next code.
Looks like it work, but I wonder, is it right way to do what I want.
I have HashMap with listeners as keys and boolean as value that determine: is listener already received last update.
Is it right way I reset HashMap?

```
private val listenersUpdateState: HashMap<WeakReference<IStatusesListener>, Boolean> = HashMap()

private fun setAllListenersToReadyToUpdate() {
    listenersUpdateState.keys.forEach { key -> 
        listenersUpdateState[key] = false
    }
}
```

Comment: An idea that might make this all simpler: Use a `MutableSet` of `WeakReference`s, and treat their presence in the set as a `true`, and their absence as `false`. To reset it, just clear the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a handy function like [Map.mapValues()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-values.html)

**Example:**

```kotlin
private val listenersUpdateState: MutableMap<WeakReference<IStatusesListener>, Boolean> = mutableMapOf()

private fun setAllListenersToReadyToUpdate() = listenersUpdateState.mapValues { false }
```

This will help not to index map again and again by `map[key]` keyword which will improove the performance!

**EDIT:**

The above code works for formulating a new map with all values set to false but to repace all values of original map see the below code

```kotlin
private fun setAllListenersToReadyToUpdate() =
    listenersUpdateState.entries.onEach { it.setValue(false) }
```

Comment: Thank you. But Map.mapValues() creates new map too.

Comment: `it.value` is a `val`, it can't be changed.

Comment: @Kiskae check the updated answer, i checked it working before updating!

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting Java 8 or above, you can use `replaceAll`:

```
listenersUpdateState.replaceAll { _, _ -> false }
```

Alternatively, you can just call `clear()` on the map, and when you retrieve values, default to false when the value is not present:

```
fun isUpdated(someRef: WeakReference<IStatusesListener>) = listenersUpdateState[someRef] ?: false
```